# How to run batch "sql" using Parse server or directly on MongoDB?

Tags: swift, mongodb, sql-update, parse-server

I am going to use SQL terminology because I am new to Parse, apologies if that is confusing.  I have a table in an app and in order to introduce new functionality I need to add a new column and set all the records to a default value.  In SQL I would just run

```
update <table> set <column> = <value>;
```

Parse Server has MongoDB as the back end and I am not clear whether the correct approach is to directly access the MongoDB and run statements through the command line or if this would cause an issue with Parse.  I found this helpful link for translating SQL syntax to MongoDB for that, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/.

I also noticed that there were some tools, such as studio 3t, but the ones I saw all required expensive licenses.  If direct MongoDB access is OK, any help understanding how to get to that would be helpful, I installed parse-server from the Bitnami stack on the AWS marketplace and to date I have only been interacting with it through the provided dashboard which doesn't have an "Update all records" option.

Right now my work around is to write a Swift script that runs the update in a loop, but I have to think that if I had millions or records instead of thousands this would be the incorrect approach.  What is the proper environment and code to update my existing Parse server so that I can run something like the SQL above?

Comment: The `mongo` shell is a free admin tool included by default with a full install of MongoDB server. The equivalent of your SQL command would be [`db.collectionname.updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) which is [included on the SQL comparison page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/#update-records) you referenced. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent method for Parse server (it seems like perhaps not?), but you should be able to find this in the [Parse docs for the API](http://docs.parseplatform.org/) you are using.

Comment: The `updateMany()` method is a part of the standard MongoDB CRUD API specification which officially supported drivers implement. If you are already comfortable using Swift, you could use the [Swift driver for MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-swift-driver) (see: [`updateMany()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-swift-driver/Classes/MongoCollection.html#/s:10MongoSwift0A10CollectionC10updateMany6filter0D07optionsAA12UpdateResultVSgAA8DocumentV_AlA0H7OptionsVSgtKF)).

Comment: Will interacting with the data have any adverse affects on the Parse Server classes?  I am not clear enough on what parse does as the middle man between the code and the database and what the risks are.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you pay attention to keep the same data formats for dates, ids, etc...

Comment: In my experience, you should be ok updating existing rows via a direct mongo connection, but creating new entries is where the parseserver middleware adds some magic (eg created at, perms, etc). Also note that the _Schema class will need updating with the new field (column) unless you already added the column via the dashboard. If you really want to be safe, you can also look into the Parse.Query.each command to programmatically step through all existing entries and update them in Cloud Code